# Как добавить шрифты через Google fonts?

Tags: html, css

Смотрю инструкцию по подключению шрифтов и не вижу у себя функции "добавить в коллекцию" https://prnt.sc/tpey91

По идее все это должно выглядеть вот так. https://prnt.sc/tpfqvk
Не могу понять что не так. Может в настройках надо что-то сделать

Comment: Не так то, что вы смотрите инструкцию устаревшую больше чем на пять лет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кликайте по карточке шрифта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираете нужную вам жирность, кликая на  **Select this style**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В правом меню будет написано, что вы выбрали:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы вставить на страницу в HTML, гугл предлагает использовать тег **<link>**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или можно вставить в CSS:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]